# терминал vs code не работает

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

При открытии терминала в нем ничего не происходит. Просто висит каретка ввода, причем ввести ничего не получается. Kill terminal не помогает ровно так же, как перезагрузка пк, вс кода и его переустановка. Удаление настроек так же не помогло. хочу интегрированый терминал использовать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я думаю, это тот случай, когда хорошо бы приложить скриншот